# How to build all subprojects in multi-module maven project with FindBugs?

Tags: maven, findbugs

I have a multi module project and I want too see **all** FindBugs errors. But when I start the build process, it finds one error at the first subproject, then skips over the rest of the build process and reports "build failed".

How can I configure the FindBugs plugin or maven build process to execute all projects and see all errors and not stop at the beginning?

Comment: what maven goal are you using? are you invoking the findbugs plugin directly or you bound it to the normal lifecycle?

Answer (score 2):

What you want is probably [failOnError](http://mojo.codehaus.org/findbugs-maven-plugin/check-mojo.html#failOnError) = false

So your POM should look something like this

```
    <plugin>
      <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
      <artifactId>findbugs-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.3</version>
      <configuration>
         <failOnError>false</failOnError>
      </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

or, alternatively, you can invoke maven with `-Dfindbugs.failOnError=false`